# Having Problems with Jumping in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I need help with my Jump Function. When I'm in game and press my space key to jump he does what he's supposed to but my problem is that the player just jumps randomly higher everytime. readyToJump Bool is set to true at Start, Jump and ResetJump Functions are executed in Update. Here's what my jump function looks like:

```
 private void Jump()
 {
     // if jump
     if (Input.GetKey(jumpKey) && readyToJump && isGrounded)
     {
         readyToJump = false;

         //reset y velocity
         rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0f, rb.velocity.z);
         // Add jump force
         rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce , ForceMode.Impulse);

         Invoke(nameof(ResetJump), jumpCooldown);
     }
 }

 private void ResetJump()
 {
     readyToJump = true;
 }
```

Comment: Why is reset jump in update?  If you reset it too soon it will be a double jump

Answer (score 0):

seems like i accidently put resetJump in Update, that was the thing that messed up my jumping movement